# Are the battens on mobile home/modular homes necessary?

Tags: drywall, walls, patching-drywall, paneling

We're buying a piece of property that has a mobile/modular home on it that's going to need quite a lot of work. The walls in the home still have the batts/battens, which we plan to remove.

Do they serve any real purpose aside from not having panels crack during transportation? Are there any important considerations to make when removing them, or can we just use tape & drywall mud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments show I have pulled battens mudded and taped over but I then shot the entire room and did a heavy knock down type of texture to help hide the slight bumps from the tape.

The [video link](https://youtube.com/watch?v=inZs0ZllsU4) that [manassehkatz](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/69578/manassehkatz-moving-2-codidact) put in the first comment has some good info, I never thought about trying to remove the surface--I just shot over it. Bad things can happen if you remove the paper.

So if you want to remove the battens I have done this using a wide knife to feather the tape bump, it was not fully to my liking so I put (sprayed) a heavy mud coat and knocked it down it looked like stucco and that hid the ripples quite well.

Got to give a + to the link for some not-to-do info. I would not have tried but some do, costing new drywall and trim.